# Incrementing scores error

Tags: php, mysqli

**QUESTION UPDATE**

Im a student and new to php, and Im currently working on a Skill Assessment project. The score that will be displayed must be 0 if i intentionally answer  all the questions wrong, but then the problem is the scores still increment. What should I do? I hope someone can help me correct my codes. Thank you!

*The strand is the question type which are ABM, HUMSS, STEM, GAS and TVL*

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $ans = $_POST['ans'];
 $abmscore = 0;
 $humssscore = 0;
 $stemscore = 0;
 $gasscore = 0;
 $tvlscore = 0;

if( !empty($ans)):
  foreach($ans as $qID => $qVal) {
    $qID =  (int) $qID;
    $qVal = (int) $qVal;

    $query1= "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rightAnswer FROM tquestions WHERE test_id = $qID AND correctanswer = $qVal";
    $result= mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
    $query2 = "SELECT strand FROM tquestions";
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 

    $query2 = "SELECT strand FROM tquestions WHERE test_id = $qID";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
    $strand =$row2['strand'];

    if($row['rightAnswer']) {
       if($strand == 'ABM' )  {
          $abmscore++;
       }

       elseif ($strand == 'HUMSS' ) {
          $humssscore++;
       }

       elseif ($strand == 'STEM' ) {
          $stemscore++;
       }

       elseif ($strand == 'GAS' ) {
          $gasscore++;
       }

       elseif ($strand == 'TVL' ) {
          $tvlscore++;
       }        
    }
  }
  endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't fecth the rows  for query2

```
  $query1= "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rightAnswer 
            FROM tquestions WHERE test_id = $qID AND correctanswer = $qVal";
  $result= mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
  // 
  $query2 = "SELECT strand FROM tquestions";
  $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
  $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
  $strand =$row2['strand'];
  //
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried the code above but the $tvlscore is the only one thats incrementing... I think somethings wrong in the else if condition. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Ohh i already saw whats the problem. I just added WHERE test_id = $qID in $query2. But the problem now is, the scores still increment even if the answers are wrong..

Comment: this is another question  ..but seems that  your  strand query is not related  to the the fact the actualt question  .is wrong or not ..  eventually you should post another question well documented  with proper data sample and the expected  result  .. when you have poste the new  question you can comment me the link